# Unable to Understand Notations in Davenport's MNT

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Chapter $15$ of Davenport's Multiplicative Number Theory writes that

> Assuming for simplicity that $T$ (which we suppose to be large) does not coincide with the
> ordinate of a zero, we have
> $$2\pi N(T)=\Delta_R \operatorname{arg} \xi(s)$$
> where $R$ is the rectangle in the $s$ plane with vertices at $2$, $2 + iT$, $-1 + iT$, $-1$ described in the positive sense.

I have the following questions

1-What is $\Delta_R$ here. I tried searching it in previous chapters but could not understand what is this notation.

2-How this equation has been derived.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I remember that $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int _{C}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\,dz=Z-P$
where $Z$ and $P$ denotes the number of zeros and number of poles inside the contour, but I am still unable to relate. How are they getting $\Delta_R \operatorname{arg} \xi(s)$ is still unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the formula
$$
2\pi N(T)=\Delta_R {\rm arg} \xi(s)
$$
the term on the RHS stands for the *increment* of the argument of $\xi(s)$ along the boundary of the rectangle $R$, i.e., the change in the argument along the path of the boundary of $R$.

For details see for example [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/243040515_The_argument_of_the_Riemann_zeta_function), page $436$. How this is connected to the argument principle, see [here](https://travorlzh.github.io/2021/01/19/zeta-zeros-count.html), or [here](https://hp.hisashikobayashi.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Riemann-Hypothesis-No.-7-July-14.pdf), page $10$.